# How to make another key function as a spacebar in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, keyboard

We have an older laptop that is still used a lot and works fine... accept for the spacebar is not functional.  How can we assign the spacebar functions to another key - one of the Alt keys or both next to the spacebar would be best.

Comment: Auto hot key will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP does not have this function natively, you would need a third party utility to map a button to the SPACE function. Some possibilities are [KeyTweak](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/keytweak.html) or [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35/)

Comment: SharpKeys was crap all the way around (maybe it was XP) but KeyTweak was really easy to use and worked.  Thank you.

Comment: KeyTweak is what I used a few times, I added SharpKeys via a Google search because I didn't want to recommend a specific piece of software without an alternative of some kind, To be honest, I never tried it.